# Resize Form and load a control

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, controls

Is it possible to have this?

Initial size when the form load
[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/1011696_599367370082426_1474298965_n.jpg))</sub>

When the button is click the size of form will increase and a control will be loaded.
[image: 2]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/7242_599367596749070_579963043_n.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add and re-size controls at run time. In a new Visual Studio project look in the Form1.Designer.cs and you will see all the code necessary to accomplish this.

For example I have created a blank form with a `ComboBox`

```
            // comboBox1
            // 
            this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(83, 99);
            this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
            this.comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 28);
            this.comboBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(278, 245);
            this.Controls.Add(this.comboBox1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

Additionally you might want to consider the TableLayoutView if you want the controls to dynamically re-size. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx

Or if your goal is just to add a label or any other control to the form with a button you would just put the following in the button click event...

```
// this will re-size the form to whatever size(x,y) you want.
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);
```

and to add a comboBox for example

```
            ComboBox comboBox2 = new ComboBox();
            comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
            comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(83, 99);
            comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
            comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 28);
            comboBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.Controls.Add(comboBox2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use the `Click` event of the button to change the `Width`, `Height` and other properties of the form, using `this.Height = x;` etc. You can also change similar properties for the control that is already visible on the form.

[MSDN: Form Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_properties.aspx)

You can either dynamically create the new control, and add it to the form's `Controls` collection, or have it initially not visible, and use code to show it.

Answer (score 0):

If you increase the size of your form, and then place the second control in the area you will want it to show up, you can then decrease the size of the form so the control appears to be hidden in the designer.  However it is in fact still there, so if you run it and increase the window size you should be able to see it.

Another way to do this would be to add a handler for your form `Resize` event, which checks to see if the form reaches a certain size; if so, another control becomes visible.